# How do you communicate UI changes to developers while working remotely?

Tags: website-design

This is something that I've had an issue with for so long. Even though we provide stylesheets, style guides, assets, etc and do an entire workshop explaining the design - more often than not the link sent back to check looks nothing like the design. 
Are there any tools available to communicate this better to developers?

Comment: How to communicate it better is a step too far ahead, you should find out why there is a miscommunication. In my experience it helps when the designer understands front-end development to get the best result.

Comment: What I mean is, find out whether the problem is the design itself or indeed the way it is communicated.

Comment: I agree with @jazZRo about finding out if there is any miscommunication. Perhaps there is still something that is too vague. Have you tried clickable prototypes?

Answer (score 4):

Having worked on both sides of this wall in the past, here are a few issues you might have to solve:

#### Your development team may have technical skill gaps.

HTML might seem like a prerequisite skill for developers working on websites, but actually it is often overlooked, in favor of more technical skills. Even “front-end” developers (who are experts in JavaScript) often don’t really know HTML and CSS well.

#### Some developers may have disdain for design

If your development team is rushed to meet deadlines, they will make the functionality work first. Making it look like the comp only happens “if there’s time.”

#### *Some* Developers simply don’t have an eye for design at all

Do you have any of those developers on your team who always wear wrinkled, stained shirts, and mismatched socks? Are you expecting these folks to be able to be able to “dress” your website any better than they dress themselves?

#### The organization may standardize on technologies that make it harder to match your design

Do you know what technologies the website is built on, and the constraints they impose? If your developers are constantly putting square pegs (your mockups) into round holes (your libraries and frameworks) you are going to get poor results.

#### There could be browser compatibility issues

The developers might not be ensuring the product looks correct in the browsers you are using.

#### Your mockups might be naive

Designers sometimes ask for things that are contrary to how browsers or other environments “want” to behave. Are you asking developers to override standard functionality, but that’s not being factored into time estimates?

#### Developers might be resisting some of your ideas

Senior developers may actually be secretly rolling their eyes at certain parts of the mockup, and developing things as they see fit.

Wise developers know that their performance reviews are often more closely tied to how well the product is ultimately received, than to adherence to the guidance you provide.

#### You might need a separate project to **implement** your design and style guides

Just because you have a style guide does not mean the development team is currently enabled to follow it. If they were expected to “catch and run with” the style guide, then the ways to implement the elements were probably never implemented in a standard and easily-repeatable way in the code.

Even if they were, if they were not properly documented, new developers may not stumble across them, and simply re-implement them, *ad hoc.*

#### Now go find out

There are some ideas about what may be going on, which I think may help you when you are trying to suss out the problems. But you will need to do a fair deal of communicating to figure out where your pain points actually are.

Comment: Great points. UX people should understand the technologies involved, especially the effort it takes to overwrite the frameworks. I, the UX lead, am currently overriding the css in Angular Material Design. Somebody has to do it - and I'm the motivated party (who is technically able to do make the changes.)

Comment: In addition to these salient points, the developers presumably also have a manager, who may or may not be the same person as your manager (if you're even an employee of the same company). Ideally this person will evangelise what you're doing and set the development team's tasks and goals accordingly, so it may be more important to work on him or her first.

Answer (score 3):

I work with many remote development teams. Communicating design to these remote teams is challenging but you need to work harder to make this work.

You cannot just chuck your design "assets" over the fence and expect the remote developers to understand it.

You need to "hold their hands" and walk them through the design and the assets. Video conferencing software (e.g. like WebEx, etc.) allows you to show things live.

Always ask your remote development team to reflect back their understanding to you.

Always have regular meetings to "show & tell" progress - you don't want to wait until the end to see what they have done.